# Microsoft Azure Bot App Skype Channel not Working

Tags: azure, bots, botframework, skype

I have now spent too much time on this issue and still can't seem to fix it.

I have an Azure Bot and I have configured it for Microsoft Teams and Skype.
They do not seem to be working.

The Skype Bot Publish is still 'inReview', I can add the Bot as a contact on skype/teams and when I send a message it is 'Sent' according to Skype, but I do not get a reply.

The Azure Webchat (Test in Webchat) works flawlessly on the Azure Web interface.
There must be something that I'm missing?

Since the last update there does not seem to be an updated how to or explanation to the newly added fields.

When you publish the Skype channel there is an option:
Bot website? What should be put here?

[image: Bot Website]

Also on the Calling section:
Webhook (for calling) 
[image: Webhook]

Thank you.

More pictures:

[image: Channels]

[image: Message stats where skype is hit]

[image: Web chat working]

Comment: do you really want to publish the bot on skype (meaning making it discoverable on the skype directory) or do you only want to use it on Skype?

Comment: Hi, not sure what you are referring to?
All I want to do is be able to message and call the bot through skype.

Comment: OK, so you don't need to publish it. That step is not required. For Skype-Calling bot, check the sample https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/skype-CallingBot

Comment: Thanks, I should also mention that I am using many of Microsoft Azure's Cognitive services with the bot. Does this have any effect on your previous comment? 'Messages, Images, Voice are all input.

Comment: Nope at all, you don't need to publish the bot even if you are using external services.

Comment: I still want to know what I am doing incorrectly to not have the bot respond through the Skype channel.

Comment: My skype channel is still "inReview", Who can I contact to pay/expedite this?
I have even changed my bot subscription to a paid one to hopefully get faster response.

Comment: I'm still not sure why you want to get your bot published. Your bot is not working because other reason not because is not published to the skype directory. In fact, since the bot is not working, the review won't succeed. Better you explain exactly what you are doing so you can help you get your bot in skype up and running.

Comment: What do you mean with the "bot isn't working" ?
The bot works on the Emulator and Through Azure Test in Web App.

All i want to do is add the Bot on Skype, and receive responses if I type?

This was the Process:
Create Web App Bot on Azure, Use LUIS Template, and expand on it with different dialogs.
All of this works during testing? 

And one of the questions that I have regarding the Skype inReview section I still would like answered.

Comment: Also to add.
Even a simple Echo bot does the same.
Maybe I am Missing something here? 
I use .NET with Microsoft Bot framework. Here is a simple piece of code that sends a message to the user: 

private async Task ShowLuisResult(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
await context.PostAsync($"Some TEXT");
}

Comment: In order to use it Skype you have to 1) configure the ngrok url in the bot, 2) add the bot in Skype following the link provided by the bot framework portal 3) have the bot running locally and in the port you configure ngrok against

Comment: Okay, so do I just use the skype channel I made on azure as the local bot's (One in the link you make) App settings? 

Also, how do I test this bot on skype?